# Twitter integration for member profiles

Tags: add-on, members, twitter

We are running a membership site using EE v2.5.3 and would like to output a member's latest tweets on their profile page. Could you suggest the best add-on/ solution to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: We try to avoid entirely opinion based questions here, as they don't provide much value. It would be best if you can least mention the add-ons you've researched so far, and what you're worried they might fall short on.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EE_Twitter](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee_twitter).  It works with the 1.1 API and, once set up, you should be able to do something like:

```
<h3>Latest tweets</h3>
{exp:twitter:user screen_name="biz" limit="5"}
    {text}
{/exp:twitter:user}
```

More documentation at https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter.  This is a free (and very nicely done) module.